# Using 'auto' type deduction - how to find out what type the compiler deduced?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, c++-chrono

How can I find out what type the compiler deduced when using the `auto` keyword?

Example 1: Simpler

```
auto tickTime = 0.001;
```

Was this deduced as a `float` or a `double?`

Example 2: More complex (and my present headache):

```
typedef std::ratio<1, 1> sec;
std::chrono::duration<double, sec > timePerTick2{0.001};
 auto nextTickTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + timePerTick2;
```

What type is `nextTickTime`?

The problem I'm having is when I try to send `nextTickTime` to `std::cout`. I get the following error:

```
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:143:16: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
  std::cout << std::setprecision(12) << nextTickTime << std::endl; // time in seconds
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39:0,
             from ./main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >]’
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

Comment: When in doubt, I cheat. Make a cheap hack program that declares the auto variable but doesn't use it, then check what the debugger thinks it is.

Comment: Which debugger are you using?

Comment: Trick works in Visual Studio. Can't remember if it works in gdb.

Comment: I use `eclipse IDE` and most of the time I just hover the mouse over the `auto` keyword and the deduced type pops up.

Comment: @Galik speaks the truth. Just fired up Eclipse to test if it worked in GDB and didn't have to go that far. It does work, though. Small problem: Can't seem to convince `timepoint` to sum with a `double`.

Comment: Oops sorry, I that was supposed to be the duration. Will fix.

Comment: The most reliable hack which works in any IDE - Just Dont Use `auto` :) Seriously, if you're really concerned about which type deduced exactly why would you use `auto` which can result in different type under diferent circumstances?

Comment: There's defined rules that compilers adhere to, to determine what type it will be. If you're worried about what type it will be deduced as, explicitly type it as `Diligent` suggested.

Comment: Totally understand the "don't use `auto`" argument, but there are times when you are trying to stuff a result into what you think the type should be,  and the error messages take quite a bit of parsing to figure out what the type really is. A hack with `auto` can show you the way really fast.

Comment: [Howard's response (and improvement)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c/20170989#20170989) was interesting; `type_name<decltype(nextTickTime)>()` prints `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >` for your case... although I may actually like @mrtnj's answer better :).

Comment: Ehm ... what am I missing? It's right there in the error message?

Comment: about `auto tickTime = 0.001;`: [without `f`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3696902/995714) the literal is a [double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12205141/995714)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser blasphemy! Ch2, item5 of Meyers' Effective Modern C++ clearly states, "Prefer ``auto`` to explicit type declarations."

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I like to use idea from *Effective Modern C++* which uses non-implemented template; the type is output with compiler error:

```
 template<typename T> struct TD;
```

Now for auto variable `var`, after its definition add:

```
 TD<decltype(var)> td;
```

And watch error message for your compiler, it will contain type of `var`.

Comment: would a `template<typename T> void td(T t);` also work for the auto variable var?

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, but then you will get linker error and not compilation error. Compiation errors are shown earlier.

Answer (score 39):

A lo-fi trick that doesn't require any prior helper definitions is:

```
typename decltype(nextTickTime)::_
```

The compiler will complain that `_` isn't a member of whatever type `nextTickTime` is.

Comment: Does not work. However just `decltype(example)::_;` does work. I've submitted an edit to this answer but while that will probably stay pending ~forever I thought I'd include a comment as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of it not working. Here's [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/GPdsWWc8M) of `typename decltype(nextTickTime)::_` working.

Comment: [Example with `typename` not working](https://godbolt.org/z/89z7WPrv8). If however you replace with `decltype(nextTickTime)::_;` it will will give you the correct error.

Comment: Was about to suggest an answer and saw you already did that. +1

Answer (score 10):

Here's a `typeid` version that uses `boost::core::demangle` to get the type name at runtime.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::literals;

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

template<typename T>
std::string type_str(){ return boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name()); }

auto main() -> int{
    auto make_vector = [](auto head, auto ... tail) -> std::vector<decltype(head)>{
        return {head, tail...};
    };

    auto i = 1;
    auto f = 1.f;
    auto d = 1.0;
    auto s = "1.0"s;
    auto v = make_vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    std::cout
    << "typeof(i) = " << type_str<decltype(i)>() << '\n'
    << "typeof(f) = " << type_str<decltype(f)>() << '\n'
    << "typeof(d) = " << type_str<decltype(d)>() << '\n'
    << "typeof(s) = " << type_str<decltype(s)>() << '\n'
    << "typeof(v) = " << type_str<decltype(v)>() << '\n'
    << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints this on my system:

```
typeof(i) = int
typeof(f) = float
typeof(d) = double
typeof(s) = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
typeof(v) = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
```

Comment: Can you give example output? I’m curious if it’s the same as in the compiler error messages, of it Boost does something more clever?

Answer (score 5):

typeid can be used to get the type of variable most of the time.  It is compiler dependent and I've seen it give strange results.  g++ has RTTI on by default, not sure on the Windows side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

typedef std::ratio<1, 1> sec;
int main()
{
    auto tickTime = .001;
    std::chrono::duration<double, sec > timePerTick2{0.001};
    auto nextTickTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + timePerTick2;
    std::cout << typeid(tickTime).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(nextTickTime).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

./a.out | c++filt

double
std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >
```

Comment: Referring to "the Windows side" doesn't make much sense. GCC works on Windows, and so do other popular compilers, so I assume you're referring to Microsoft's compiler. Indeed, RTTI is on by default for MSVC as well. You have to explicitly turn it off with `/GR-`. You'll get a `bad_typeid` exception if you try to use `typeid` when compiling with `/GR-`, so the problem will be quite obvious. (Of course, *any* C++ compiler would have to have RTTI on by default because otherwise, it is in utter violation of the language standard.)

Comment: @CodyGray: It's quite common for the default setting of a compiler not to be in accord with the standard.  If you want a standard compliant compiler, you usually need to add some options.

Comment: My experience suggests it is relatively common for a compiler's default options to *relax* standards-compliance, but disabling fundamental language features like RTTI or exceptions seems much too far. I haven't seen a normal (i.e., non-embedded or other special use case) compiler that disables either of these things out-of-the-box. @martin

Comment: This code doesn't use RTTI. These expressions' runtime types are statically known at compile time, they are not polymorphic. It will compile and run flawlessly with RTTI disabled.

Comment: I get a compile failure with RTTI disabled under OS X. 
g++ -std=c++11 -g -fno-rtti junk.cpp

junk.cpp:16:18: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
    std::cout << typeid(tickTime).name() << std::endl;

Comment: g++ outputs the type's mangled name when you use `type_info::name()`, while MSVC outputs the demangled name (i.e. g++ outputs `int` as `i`, while MSVC sees it internally as `H` and outputs `int`).  To get the mangled name on MSVC, you have to use the non-standard `type_info::raw_name()` (which seems to prepend a period for some reason, so it would give `.H` for `int` instead of `H`).  This might explain some of the strange results.

Answer (score 2):

A low tech solution is hover the mouse over `nextTickTime` which in some GUIs gives the type else set a `.` after `nextTickTime` in the `cout` and select a reasonable looking value or function.

In general if You *know* what type You get use `auto` if you *don't know* it don't use it. Which is a bit counter intuitive.

So if you know its a interator just use auto to reduce the incantations, if the result is some **unknown** type you have to find out what it is before using `auto`.

See also [Herb, Andrei and Scott discussing `auto`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Andrei-and-Herb-Ask-Us-Anything#time=25m03s)

Comment: "If you don't know don't use it" makes no sense when templates are involved.

Answer (score 2):

As [Daniel Jour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116364/daniel-jour) said, read the error message:

```
... _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<
           std::chrono::_V2::system_clock,
           std::chrono::duration<
             double, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > ...
```

Comment: True. In the case where a compiler error is thrown the type can be found in the error message; however, the question is directed at cases where the code successfully compiles, and there is no error message.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to force a compile error, which shows the type of `tickTime`:

```
struct {} baD = tickTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type deduced by the compiler is in the error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>;
 _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >]’
  ^^   <-------- the long type name --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

It's a complicated type name but it is there in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to code:

```
decltype(whateverYouWantTheTypeOf)::_;
```

Your compiler will give you an error will reveal the type of `whateverYouWantTheTypeOf` (could even be an expression). Example errors:

```
# clang++ error on something defined as auto
type 'decltype(length)' (aka 'long') cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
        decltype(length)::_;
# g++ error on an expression
error: ‘_’ is not a member of ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float> >::difference_type’ {aka ‘long int’}
   27 |  decltype(last - first)::_;
```

Comment: Based on John McFarlane's answer but fixed to work in all cases. I did already try submitting an edit.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, to effectively print out the value in `nextTickTime` you should explicitly convert to a suitable [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) and output the result of [`duration::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count).

```
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::seconds;

auto baseTime = ...;
std::cout << std::setprecision(12) << duration_cast<seconds>(nextTickTime - baseTime).count()
    << std::endl; // time in seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

@jonathan-oconnor [points out](https://twitter.com/ninkibah/status/1344268669212356609) that you can use the [`[[deprecated]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) attribute introduced in C++14 to produce a very clean solution:

```cpp
template<typename T>
[[deprecated]] constexpr void printType(T const&) {}
```

Unfortunately though, the diagnostic emitted by MSVC doesn't mention the type. ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/ETjbx4))